# VS Code -Python

Tags: visual-studio-code

Installed the latest version of VS code and now when I run scripts in the terminal and they require a string input, instead of simple accepting the string I get an error message 'not defined'. So I have to put "" around the input for it to recognise the input as a string and accept it. This didn't used to be the case I wonder where I can change the setting?

Is there a setting in VS code that would allow strings to be accepted by the integrated terminal as strings without the “”?

Comment: I think that it's just a update which makes it *clearer* to understand for other readers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you add any example what you're trying to do here?

Comment: Just tested `print(input("Say Hello"))`  with the latest version and the standard Python extension, neither internal nor external terminal require me to put quotes around the input. Please share the code where you do.  This may also be due to something in your launch.json file

Comment: so, you want to be able to type `print(hello)` in the terminal and have it interpret `hello` as as string not a variable?  sounds dangerous?

Comment: No I mean when using input. So when eg asking for a name in the terminal, you used to be able to just type is and it would be accepted as a string. Now it doesn’t and requires you to put in speech marks to  identify it as a string.

Comment: It's working now with the integrated terminal after re-installing VS Code. Maybe it was something with the launch.json file. I am only getting to grips with using VSCode recently.